# Magento 2 : Title Prefex and Suffix Doesn't Works

Tags: magento2, websites, page-title

I have 2 websites with Magento 2.2.2 with luma theme.
For one prefix and suffix works fine. For other, no prefix and suffix are rendering.

Who can explain me exactly where part of the code is used to generate the title I will try to debug it.
Thanks a lot, guys

Comment: Please change the store view for other website and add your products and suffix from store - configuration

Answer (score 0):

From what you described I think it's most likely scope issue with your configuration setting.

You can use `php bin/magento config:show` to see what value has been set for `head_title_prefix` and `head_title_suffix`

However if you want to look into the code for debug put a breakpoint in vendor/magento/module-theme/Model/Design/Config/DataProvider.php::getMeta()

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for you help.

With php bin/magento config:show I don't undestand why my prefix and suffix are empy 
design/head/default_title - What's Up
design/head/title_prefix -
design/head/title_suffix -
design/head/default_description - Default Description
design/head/default_keywords -
design/head/includes -

In catalog I can see my separator :
catalog/seo/title_separator -  -

But in my backend configuration I can see the value :
 Page Title Prefix ok
 Page Title Suffix <ok

So If the command configuration can't see it it's normal it wasn't apply. But why ?